# Using AdditionalConfiguration.php for many TYPO3 Installation?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I use one global AdditionalConfiguration.php for serveral TYPO3 Installation. I just symlink this file.

```
AdditionalConfiguration.php -> /global/typo3_every_instance/typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php
```

Now in this AdditionalConfiguration.php I can enforce the use of rsa for every TYPO3 Instance:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['loginSecurityLevel'] = 'rsa';
```

I too have a configuration for maxFileSize there:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['maxFileSize'] = '20240'
```

But on some installation I want to have a bigger maxFileSize, so I have this in my LocalConfiguration.php:

```
'BE' => array('maxFileSize' => 150000)
```

Now I changed the  AdditionalConfiguration.php to:

```
/* if not set in LocalConfiguration maxFileSize has default value */
if($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['maxFileSize'] == '10240'){
   $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['maxFileSize'] = '20280'; // 10MB
}
```

What to you think about this?

Comment: Mybee no clear, but the configuration is working for me in a productive environment. But is it wise to use?

Answer (score 0):

what happens if the default value changes for some reason?

I do not know whether the AdditionalConfiguration.php is read before or after the 
LocalConfiguration.php?

If your LocalConfiguration.php is read after AdditionalConfiguration.php
just set the new value.

if it's the other way round you can try following code
in LocalConfiguration

```
 define("FILESIZE",'150000');
```

in AdditionalConfiguration

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['maxFileSize'] = defined("FILESIZE")?FILESIZE:'20240'
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Ok, the change in the default is a problem. I expect them only change on LTS, not on minor.

Comment: AdditionalConfiguration.php is read after LocalConfiguration.php!

Comment: Its not possible to write just anything into LocalConfiguration.php because it's overwritten frequently and everything is kicked out what TYPO3 does not understand.

Comment: if you can't change the localConfiguration then your way is OK,

Comment: perhaps a bit dirty - why not set the filesize to something like 150001
it wouldn't hurt and a test whether 'BE' => array('maxFileSize' => 150000) % 10 == 0 would reveal whether there is a changed value.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the way to go is the TYPO3 Application Context. You can set single values inside an if in your AdditionalConfiguration.php or even just load a specific one for each context, e.g. AdditionalConfigurationTesting.php.
Here is a great article how to set and use this: https://usetypo3.com/application-context.html

In the future in modern docker environments its probably more the way to go with .env files - filled with your local settings.